# Dynamic domain/link in Email Alerts

Tags: email-template, email-alert, force.com-sites

Scenario: I am using Salesforce sites to display a form where a user can enter some data. When a user finshes, I have an email alert setup with a link in it to send the user to another page on the site.

Problem: Setting the URL on the link in the email alert to direct to the Sandbox version of the site if the email is being tested from Sandbox, and vice-versa for Production. None of the $Site global variables assist here because the email alert does not come from the Site domain. I'd rather not hard-code this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came up w a simple solution that works for email alerts, I think it would work for a site but have not tested.

Create a formula field on User with the following structure (which I got from [this SE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor))

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))
```

Then use that field in the email alert, with the syntax {!User.FieldName__c}

Per [the salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=merge_fields_email_templates.htm&language=en_US), the User fields represent the sending user on the email alert, so it should always be populated.

> User Fields—Use these merge fields to represent the sending user.
>   Merge fields named {!User.field_name} return values from the user
>   record of the person who created or updated the record that triggered
>   the workflow rule.

This is working on email alerts in my instance.  I previously would create formula fields on each object using the Partner URL, but was looking for a way to only create one field and reference it.  Since global variables are not accessible, this solution came to mind.  Let me know if it works on sites, I think it should.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've come up with is to use a Custom Label as a placeholder for the URL. Then it is just a matter of referencing $Label.label_name in the Email Templates for the url, and then there is only one place to update the Domain after moving to Production.

I would love to hear other ways though!

Comment: This is not environment/sandbox free. To avoid post deployment step of editing the URLs in email templates we can use a formula field - `LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_360, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_360))` and the use this formula field in merge fields