# $API No Longer Available in Formula Editor

Tags: formula, email-template

I was trying to implement the [trick of using $Api.Partner_Server_URL_260](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor) to get the base url for an email template, but when I try to use it in a new org, I realized that $Api isn't available anymore. I checked one of my developer orgs and it isn't there either. Did something change with a recent release? Can we no longer use this trick?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized I was in the formula editor for field default values and not for a formula field. If I select a formula field, I can still use $Api.