# Salesforce Page with unique ID?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

We have a public SF site which is a visualforce form with few questions.

How can we send this form to customers so the response would be saved to their Account record?

Is it possible to set the form end with customers SF ID, which is then used to post the result to the Account record with this ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is exactly what the standard controller was designed for. You can access specific fields, save, and cancel without writing a single line of `Apex` code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" immediate="true" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Some_Field__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
<apex:page>
```

Then you would construct a link to this page by merging the `Account.Id` into your parameters. For example, if your page were named `MyPage`, your url to the authenticated page would be:

```
<base_url> & "/apex/MyPage?id=" & <account_id>
```

You can see how to get that base url here: [How do I get the base URL in the formula editor?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor)

To link to a specific page in your `Site`, have a read of [Determine the URL of a Site.com Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/siteforce_communities_url.htm)
.

That should get you started!