# Get instance domain in Custom Button

Tags: custom-button, mydomain, url-encode

For my custom button with Content Source = URL I use following formula text to get instance domain:

```
LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_390, FIND('/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_390))
```

that returns "https://vfirst-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/"

But when I click the button it navigated me to following URL that is includes necessary part with encoded domain:

https://vfirst-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/servlet/https%3A%2F%2Fvfirst-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com%2F

Please assist, what I do wrong? How I can just go to domain URL when I click the button?

Comment: From your second link, it seems you are forwarding to the same domain. In this case you don't need instance name, you can use relative path. See this SFSE link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor

Comment: We need to go to visualforce page with URL that starts with vfirst.eu6.visual.force.com where "vfirst" - namespace of our developer instance. Relative URL will get start as eu6.visual.force.com (with it we get "Page does not exist" error). So we need make some additional manipulations with URL (add namespace) that we can do only if it is absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link manipulation doesn't work properly with *Content Source* as `URL`, URL type `OnClick JavaScript` is advised to use for such requirement.

Following works for me:

```
var baseUrl = "{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_390, 
    FIND('/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_390))}";

alert("baseUrl: " + baseUrl);
```

Output:

> baseUrl: https://forcetrekker-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/

---

Added:

For navigation withing Salesforce, you can use relativeURL with *URL* as *Content Source*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there other ways to not use onclick javascript? Problem is the Lightning Experience does not support onclick javascript buttons but we really need lightning compatibility.

Comment: Updated answer, did you try using a relative URL?

Comment: Yes, but so I have another issue. We need to go to visualforce page with URL that starts with https://vfirst.eu6.visual.force.com where "vfirst" - namespace of our developer instance. Relative URL will get start as https://eu6.visual.force.com (with it we get "Page does not exist" error). So we need make some additional manipulations with URL (add namespace) that we can do only if it is absolute.

Comment: Can you not use `{!$Page.PageName}`? It takes care of namespace as well.

Comment: Seems button with Content Source as URL does not support $Page. I got error: "Field $Page.vfirst__SearchButtons does not exist".

Answer (score 0):

Some might wanna try this too, to get a base URL in JS for Custom Button

```
var baseURL = '{! URLFOR("[restofurl]" + [anyvariabletoadd]) }';
```

Comment: You shouldn't be still using `var` in 2019.