# Hard coded images - How to convert

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Our Salesforce Org is moving from na6 to na70
I have been trying to find a way to convert this:

```
<img src="https://c.na6.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=12345678" alt="Get Support"/>
```

I could just replace the na6 with na70, but I wonder if there is a better way, by using mydomain or even by having a dynamic link. (i.e. /12345678).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: see also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor

Answer (score 3):

You can set the url dynamically by using the getSalesforceBaseUrl() method in the URL class. This will always get the current instance for the org so you don't have to manually update it each time.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm

Comment: I did see this, but was wondering if there was another easier option, like a global variable that could be used directly from visualforce without the need of a class and test class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using My Domain, you'll get a different URL, which looks like this:

```
https://mydomain.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=123456
```

You **can** hardcode this URL, because it will never change despite moving from one pod (instance) to another.

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working for content.force.com. Are you able to show a screenshot of it working for you?

Comment: @MicroSumol https://phyrfox-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0155000000342Iq&oid=00D500000007NT9&lastMod=1538921375000

Comment: @sfdcfox amazingly that link still works lol