# How to get correct lightning instance name in a Text Formula field?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, formula

We have a field on a custom object called 'Switch_to_LTNG_Url__c' which is a formula field and returns a text consisting of the url. The formula is as follows:

```
'https://ourprodinstance.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+CASESAFEID(Id)+'/view'
```

The issue is that it always returns a URL to the prod instance and we want it to be dynamic based on the environment it is in.

How do we get a consistent URL to the instance in which the field resides?

So that if it is in QA, it should get:

```
'https://ourprodinstance--qa.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?#/sObject/LONGID78787387382/view'
```

UPDATE: Need to use the field in email templates so need the base lightning URL computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the base URL for this. Just use a relative URL:

```
'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+CASESAFEID(Id)+'/view'
```

Salesforce is smart enough to automatically switch the user to Lightning when you navigate to the Salesforce App.

Comment: That makes perfect sense @sfdcfox

Comment: @kratos For an email template, you can use the {!$Object.Link} formulas (see the editor for specifics), or see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/3816/2984) for other alternatives.

Comment: Will do ! Thanks again @sfdcfox