# HyperLink in record triggered flow

Tags: apex, lightning, visual-workflow, email-template, salesforce-id

[image]I have requirement to append contact link as url in email action in record trigger flow

1. I have used Custom label stored as base url like: test.salesforce.com
2. Created formula:  {!$Label.Base_Url}&{!$Record.Id}

working fine but every time when I refresh Sandbox I need to update url in custom label

Please suggest is there any other  way instead of hardcoded url.

I can use class email template instead of flow email action to get URL like contact.detailedlink
but according to my requirement its not much suitable to use classic email template and send as email alert

Comment: $Site.BaseUrl instead of $Label.Base_Url, perhaps?

Comment: Looks like $site global variable not available in flow. @sfdcfox

Comment: I wasn't sure, I don't use flows a lot.

Comment: thanks though for your quick response !@sfdcfox

Comment: can you use this hoary old trick - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor?

Comment: I have tried by referring above link  {!LEFT({!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_260},FIND('.com',{!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_260})+4)+{!$Record.Id}}}  but not sure I am getting as text

Comment: I am getting like this {!LEFT(https://test--b2bindst.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/26.0/00D030000008acy,FIND('.com',https://test--b2bindst.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/26.0/00D030000008acy)+4)+0030300000JgnFaAAJ}} looks like very close @cropredy

Answer (score 4):

*Sorry for the delay*

I created a formula field in the Flow called `detailLink` and defined as:

```
LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_510, FIND( '/services',
    $Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_510)) & 
    {!$Record.Id}
```

Then, referenced this formula field in the Email action

[image]

Comment: Thanks !! @cropredy

Comment: @cropredy I'm using this formula, but how could I make it as a hyperlink?

Comment: @Ana - Not sure I understand your question, my answer renders in the screen flow as a clickable hyperlink.  If you have a different question, post a new question with example of what you've tried and your desired result

Comment: @cropredy I post it:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375416/how-could-i-add-an-hyperlink-in-custom-notification-using-flow/375419#375419

Comment: This is great thank you! 