# How could I add an hyperlink in Custom Notification using Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, custom, notification, hyperlink

I want to display a custom notification with the hyperlink of the record, but i'm only getting a text with the URL and HTML tags.

**The custom notification:**

[image]

**Notification body:**

[image]

**linkToTheOrderRecord:**

[image]

**The notification:**
i'm getting in html format  :(
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already set the target record id for your notification. If you click on the notification it should take you there without building your own hyperlink.

The body of a notification doesn't allow you to use html tags. This means you won't be-able to build a formatted hyperlink. (Even if you could, it wouldn't work properly since clicking anywhere in the entire notification should take you to the target record.)