# How to add Base URL to a formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, url, hyperlink, urlfor

I have a formula field where in I am displaying a url in the text message. The formula looks like this "https://mycompany--staging.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/"&Id but I want this url as a base url so that I can use it in production too. I do not want to add another link just for production. I dont need to add any code as well. Just need to edit this url so that it works in all environments. i tried adding "/" but it doesnt work. Please sugest! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the HYPERLINK function.

For example:

```
HYPERLINK('/'+ Id, 'Redirect to Id', '_blank')
```

The system will redirect using the current base URL automatically, adding the Id of the current record.

You can play with the URL of the page you want to reach, for example, if you want to edit a Contact using this approach, you can:

```
HYPERLINK('/lightning/r/Account/'+ Account__r.Id+'/edit, 'Edit Account', '_blank')
```

The system will read the Account of the current record and open the edit view of it.

For reference always see what the URL of whatever you want to open looks like:

[image]

I would recommend as well you check this document: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_hyperlink_formula_fields.htm&type=5

I hope this helps! Have a nice day.

Comment: I have used Hyperlink function before this formula but we are using this formula field in a  text message and in that text message it gives anchor tag which does not look good.

Comment: Oh, well... that's an important piece of information missing from the original question. Did you try this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-i-get-the-base-url-in-the-formula-editor @user134185